# How to submit a selected value without a submit button?

Tags: php, javascript

I have this code

```
<Select>
<option value="-1">Select</option>
<option value="6">kasper </option> 
<option value="13">adad </option> 
<option value="14">3204 </option>                   
</select>
```

I am using this button to submit the selected choice of the user:

```
<input type="submit" name="pageaction" value="Select" />
```

When the user click on `"Select"` it will display information corresponding to his select.

Can it be without the button?

Regards to all,

Comment: The question is not clear - how are you hoping it would work if you take the button away?

Comment: You mean when the user chooses some option it gets submitted? i'm not understanding the question very well...

Comment: You can do this with JavaScript and the [onChange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onchange).

Comment: I think using javascript this can be done, but don't know how ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can call function inside the select dropdown.

```
 <select id="sel_id" name="sel_name"  onchange="this.form.submit();">
<option value="-1">Select</option>
<option value="6">kasper </option> 
<option value="13">adad </option> 
<option value="14">3204 </option>                   
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just want to let you know that I have many submit buttons in the same form . how to refer to this button?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null at HTMLSelectElement.onchange`

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function selectChange(val) {
    //Set the value of action in action attribute of form element.
    //Submit the form
    $('#myForm').submit();
}
</script>
<head>
<form id="myForm" action="test.html">
    <Select onChange=selectChange(this.value)>
        <option value="-1">Select</option>
        <option value="6">kasper </option> 
        <option value="13">adad </option> 
        <option value="14">3204 </option>                   
    </select>
</form>
</html>
```

Download jquery from:
 http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/21/jquery-1-7-1-released/

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the problem is that I have many submit buttons in my HTML page, how can I tell the java script function to submit this action

Comment: Many submit buttons means many form element??
If yes then you can submit individual form by its id as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to submit the form like:

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="post">
    <Select onchange="myform.submit()" name="test">
    <option value="-1">Select</option>
    <option value="6">kasper </option> 
    <option value="13">adad </option> 
    <option value="14">3204 </option>                   
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="myform" id ="myform" method="post">

<select id="sel_id" name="sel_name"  onchange="submitform();">
<option value="-1">Select</option>
<option value="6">kasper </option> 
<option value="13">adad </option> 
<option value="14">3204 </option>                   
</select>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```